# Proof idea - closed subspace of compact metric space is compact

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

I came up with the following proof and I am afraid it is too simple and that I missed something...

Question: If $X$ is a compact metric space and $M \subset X$ is closed, show $M$ is compact.

Proof idea: We know that $X$ compact gives that $X$ is closed and bounded. To show that $M$ is compact we must just show that $M$ is bounded since it is given that $M$ is closed. But since $M \subset X$ and $X$ is bounded doesn't that immediately give that $M$ is bounded?

Comment: Not every closed bounded subset of a metric space is compact!

Comment: ok. Thank you. I will check into what else needs to be satisfied.

Comment: Hint: for metric spaces, compact is equivalent to sequentially compact. So, show that $M$ is sequentially compact instead.

Comment: Why aren't all closed and bounded subsets of a metric space compact?

Comment: Consider $\{x \in \mathbb{Q} : x^2 < 2\} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$, with the usual topology. Closed and bounded, but not compact.

Comment: Thank you. Does the definition of compact being closed and bounded apply to anything? I felt like I knew that definition from somewhere... edit: oh I see I think. That is used for finite dimensional normed spaces maybe...

Comment: It's true in any complete metric space, which does include "finite dimensional normed spaces over $\mathbb{R}$" (since they're, in some sense, just $\mathbb{R}^n$). Definitely shouldn't be taken as the definition, as the one about open covers and finite subcovers is very much the right definition.

Comment: Actually, it is not true in any infinite dimensional vector space, since the unit ball in these ambients is not compact, although it is clearly bounded and closed.

Comment: This is one case where the general definition, for arbitrary topological spaces, of compactness (every open cover of the space in question has a finite subcover) is easier to use than almost any other definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general definition of a subset of the ground set in a topological space being compact is that any open cover has a finite subcover. In general metric spaces, closed and bounded is *not* equivalent to being compact, though this holds in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

In order to proceed, suppose $X$ is a compact topological space with $M$ any closed subset with some arbitrary  open cover $C = \{O_i\}_{i\in I}$ of $M$. Then $N:=X\setminus M$ is open and adding it into the cover to form $C':=C\cup \{N\}$ is an open cover of all of $X$. Thus there is a finite subcover of $C'$ which covers $X$. Throwing out $N$ if it is included in the finite subcover of $C'$, we arrive at a finite subcover of $C$ covering $M$ as desired.

Answer (score 3):

If $X = \mathbb{R}^{n}$, then compactness is equivalent to closedness and boundedness. Otherwise, the equivalence need not hold.

A simple argument to see the desired result is as follows. Note that there is some open cover $\{ U_{\alpha} \}$ of $M$. So $\{ U_{\alpha} \} \cup F^{c}$ is an open cover of $X$. Note that there is some finite subcover of the cover.